# GridView not displaying correct thumbnail

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I have a folder on my SDCard that is hidden with the .nomedia.  I have this Imageadapter that displays the contents of the folder (Images and Videos) in a GridView.  They all seem to show up, but sometimes when I click on a thumbnail that I know is a Video, an image is displayed or even a different video.  Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong with this?

GridViewImageAdapter.class

```
package com.soboapps.todos.adapter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.ThumbnailUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class GridViewImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity mActivity;
    private ArrayList<String> mFilePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
    private int imageWidth;

    public GridViewImageAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> filePaths, int imageWidth) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.mFilePaths = filePaths;
        this.imageWidth = imageWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.mFilePaths.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.mFilePaths.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mActivity);


             if(mFilePaths.get(position).contains("jpg") || mFilePaths.get(position).contains("jpeg") ||
                     mFilePaths.get(position).contains("png"))
            {
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFilePaths.get(position)); //Creation of Thumbnail of image
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth, imageWidth));
                imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

            }
            else if(mFilePaths.get(position).contains(".mp4") || mFilePaths.get(position).contains(".3gp"))
            {
                Bitmap video = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(mFilePaths.get(position), imageWidth); //Creation of Thumbnail of video
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth, imageWidth));
                imageView.setImageBitmap(video);
            }

        }
        else 
        {
            imageView = (ImageView)convertView;
        }
        return imageView;
    }


    /*
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mActivity);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        // get screen dimensions
        Bitmap image = decodeFile(mFilePaths.get(position), imageWidth, imageWidth);

        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth, imageWidth));
        imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

        return imageView;
    }
    */



    public static Bitmap decodeFile(String filePath, int WIDTH, int HIGHT) {
        try {

            File f = new File(filePath);

            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            final int REQUIRED_WIDTH = WIDTH;
            final int REQUIRED_HIGHT = HIGHT;
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_WIDTH
                    && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_HIGHT)
                scale *= 2;

            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your getView() function you're not setting the thumbnail correctly in the case where convertView is not null. Rearrange your code like this to handle that case:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mActivity);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    if(mFilePaths.get(position).contains("jpg") || mFilePaths.get(position).contains("jpeg") ||
                 mFilePaths.get(position).contains("png"))
    {
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFilePaths.get(position));    //Creation of Thumbnail of image
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth, imageWidth));
        imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

    }
    else if(mFilePaths.get(position).contains(".mp4") || mFilePaths.get(position).contains(".3gp"))
    {
        Bitmap video = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(mFilePaths.get(position), imageWidth); //Creation of Thumbnail of video
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth, imageWidth));
        imageView.setImageBitmap(video);
    }

    return imageView;
}
```

The convertView parameter isn't a view that has already been initialized to the specified position, that you can return as is. It's a view that was being used to display a different grid element, that is being recycled for a different position, so you need to set it up.

Also, if you have laggy UI issues, look into creating your thumbnails in an AsyncTask or thread pool instead of on the main UI thread. Check out questions such as this one for information about how to do that: [Loading images in a gridview with async task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029223/loading-images-in-a-gridview-with-async-task-not-loading-correctly)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I will give this a try when I get home this evening.  And Yes... It is very laggy loading the thumbnails.  I will look into the AsyncTask.

Comment: Worked like a champ.  Now time to figure out the AsyncTask.  Thanks Again!!