# GridView Images not loaded correctly

Tags: android, gridview

I have a GridView with Image and TextViews. loading Images from URL with Async Task.

Here is the code for GridView:

```
public class GridviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> listImgUrl;
    private ArrayList<String> listCost;
    private ArrayList<String> listItem;
    private ArrayList<String> listStore;

    private Activity activity;
//  private Context context;

    public GridviewAdapter(Context context) {
        super();
    //  this.context = context;


    }

    public void GridviewAdapterInit(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> listImgUrl,
            ArrayList<String> listCost, ArrayList<String> listItem,
            ArrayList<String> listStore) {
        this.activity = activity;

        this.listImgUrl = listImgUrl;
        this.listCost = listCost;
        this.listItem = listItem;
        this.listStore = listStore;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listImgUrl.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listImgUrl.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imgViewFlag;
        public TextView tvCost;
        public TextView tvItem;
        public TextView tvStore;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder view;
        LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            view = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.gridview_row, null);

            view.imgViewFlag = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            view.tvCost = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCost);
            view.tvItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvItem);
            view.tvStore = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvStore);



            convertView.setTag(view);
        } else {
            view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


            LoadImageFromURL(listImgUrl.get(position), view.imgViewFlag);
            view.tvCost.setText(listCost.get(position));
            view.tvItem.setText(listItem.get(position));
            view.tvStore.setText(listStore.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    private void LoadImageFromURL(String url, ImageView imgView)

    {
        new ImageViewUpdator(imgView).execute(url);

    }

}
```

With above code, images are loaded correctly if images are 6 or less. When loading more images there is a problem such as images are repeated in wrong position, Few Images are not loaded. But count of images to be loaded is okay.
Not sure whats causing the problem.

Thanks for the help

Comment: this  may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029223/loading-images-in-a-gridview-with-async-task-not-loading-correctly

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load image from url then you need to use [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

> Picasso is a powerful image downloading and caching library for
>   Android.

Just one line of code solve your image loading problem :

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Comment: The problem is not in loading the Image from URL its in displaying on Gridview. loading image works fine. I'll try to use it because of it caching capability. Anyhow whats causing this problem?

Comment: is that above single line of code is enough to enable caching and loading image or do I need to add anything more ?

Comment: @Ashok please refer the doc of picasso

Comment: I used above line of code, But while scrolling images are loaded again (above code called again by rid view) is that means is it downloading images from web again !? or images are loaded from Cache. All I'm worried is more data is downloaded/consumed !?

Comment: I got it,  use Picasso.with(context).setIndicatorsEnabled(true); to know from where image is loaded. thanks to http://square.github.io/picasso/